# How to validate forgot password in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, validation, forgot-password

I want to add custom validations to the forgot password on wordpress

i have tried using this code to validate

```
add_action('validate_password_reset','validate_lost_password',10,2);
function validate_lost_password( $errors, $user)
{
    $exp = '/^(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])).{6,32}$/';

    if(!preg_match($exp, $_POST['pass1']) )
           $errors->add( 'error',  'Password must be alphanumeric.','');
}
```

when i am at the password input form, it would still submit the password i typed even if it did go inside the **if** statement which indicates the password is invalid, should not be submitted and it will show an error and ask for a new password. I have also tried adding a **return $errors;** but it still submitted the password.

Comment: Your provided code is working fine for me. Might be you are using some plugin which is conflicting with this code.

Comment: hmmm i see, this might be what's happening on my case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please try with bellow code in function.php file please

```
add_action( 'validate_password_reset' , 'se_password_min_length_check' 10, 2 );

function se_password_min_length_check( $errors, $user){
    if(strlen($_POST['pass1']) < 8)
        $errors->add( 'password_too_short', 'ERROR: password is too short.' );
}
```

Comment: this would work on others, but i just saw mine was not working because of a conflict with a plugin

Comment: Can you add it above top of the function.php file , can you show what is the error in console

Comment: i have already fixed the error on my part, but i won't be able to post the code since i just edited the shortcode that caused the conflicts of that hook. I have also accepted your answer since that should work normally just like my sample code.